# How to specify path to `llvm` for `ghc` and `cabal`?

Tags: haskell, llvm, ghc, cabal

I'm trying to add the new `llvm` path to `cabal` to build with `-fllvm` option because I receive the error that it can't see the newer version:

```
<no location info>: error:
    Warning: Couldn't figure out LLVM version!
             Make sure you have installed LLVM 5.0
```

I have LLVM 5 installed under this path: `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm@5/5.0.2/bin/`. I need to somehow tell this to `cabal` but I can't find where to do this. In `stack` there is `settings` file under the installed `ghc`, but what is the wright way to do this for `cabal`?

Comment: Program locations go to `program-locations` section of your `cabal.config`. I'm not sure there's one for `llvm` though. Perhaps you want to modify your GHC config (e.g. in /usr/lib64/ghc-8.4.1/settings) and specify full paths to llvm commands `llc`, `opt` and `clang`.

Comment: Does `cabal install --with-llc=/usr/local/Cellar/llvm@5/5.0.2/bin/llc` work (or at least produce a different error)?

Answer (score 2):

I would start with

```
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/llvm@5/5.0.2/bin/:$PATH
cabal install
```

and see if that works.

I don't see any mention of options to set the LLVM path in the GHC user guide or the `--with-PROG` section of `cabal configure --help`.  It certainly seems like a reasonable flag to add to cabal.  The [GHC guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/codegens.html#llvm-code-generator-fllvm) only mentions finding it on PATH.